# Having problem with npm install -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular-cli

Running `npm install -g @angular/cli` command throws the following warnings

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see request/request#3142

After running `ng new proj1` command, the following error is thrown:
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: what is your node version?

Answer (score 0):

`'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.` this will come if angular-cli is not successfully installed to your machine.

First update **node.js** version

Then Run the below commands

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install -g @angular/cli`